# inconsistent cumulative count in kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm using kafka streams for counting cumulative users count for each chat room.

1. Topology receives data from the 'connection' topic.
2. Each data in the 'connection' topic contains roomNo, userNo, userId, sessionId, and so on.
3. Once the kafka streams topology received the connection data, in the first processor it repartitions data with **roomNo and userNo** as a **key** and **0** as a **dummy value** and store the repartitioned data by using a KTable.
4. Next, the processor in this topology uses the groupBy method in KTable and groups the repartitioned data, by roomNo as a new key, and produces KGroupedTable.
5. Finally, the last processor part executes the count, and send the count result to the output topic named 'stat'.

This works perfectly on local and staging (or development) environments. But in the production environment, where there is a massive amount of data is transferred, the count result in the output topic 'stat' is intermittently less than the previous one.

This topology is a cumulative counter, it never decrements the count. How could this ever happen? What could possibly cause this kind of problem?

Comment: Hard to say in general. Maybe your configuration is not correct and you might loose data in between? Also note that Kafka Streams might drop record is they are considered malformed (it would be logged and recorded via metrics if this happens).

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax What metrics should I check to see if a record is dropped or not?

Comment: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/monitoring.html

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I'm using commit.interval.ms=1000 and no configuration value for cache.max.bytes.buffering. Is there any possibility for this issue to happen if the record cache (contains a lot of unique values as each key) keeps changing because of insufficient cache size?

Comment: Should not be related to buffer space, as buffering is an perf optimization and should not impact the result at all.